# RSA - Java's KeyFactory fails where bouncycastle's PEM parser succeeds

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle

I have a PEM formatted public key (received from an iOS device):

```
String pemPubKey = ""+
"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"+
"MIIBCgKCAQEA07ACQHTTrgX7ddNtyamh58xwD+S+pSrJz/Rah4zj0HIg4V/Ok5vk\n"+
"Wx6y4UyuKLCtefeiB2ipg/n1ZZ0eRac1B4UwPhAtILGQzgIUgOp0cQ3Cb94ugq92\n"+
"wxkxeEdWmIFIlXgWOf6I8yWp9DZaigrRhA2kPbY01zKxCsX1ZxKMVu2sU/HM1hJy\n"+
"aebLLND002yLzuRDLXbacmCt5U6vDQDjBmm3uZ26fEMF+GTCnn6fJBq5RDfRKjpS\n"+
"fVM0mCePO9RHiwu3oHfqoyLA2QGlCexXcIYq7KbJjC9vcamAWRqQdHlsSj5ezDTR\n"+
"GofA6HtQ+zNdGHOvqsYtbN8MJSlUXXy39wIDAQAB\n"+
"-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

If I try to parse it into a `PublicKey` using KeyFactory like that:

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
Pattern parse = Pattern.compile("(?m)(?s)^---*BEGIN.*---*$(.*)^---*END.*---*$.*");
String encoded = parse.matcher(pemPubKey).replaceFirst("$1");
byte[] pem = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(encoded);
PublicKey pubKey = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(pem));
```

I get: `java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence`.

But when I use `bouncycastle` like that:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo =
    (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) new PEMParser(new StringReader(pemPubKey)).readObject();

PublicKey pubKey;

if (PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption == subjectPublicKeyInfo.getAlgorithm().getAlgorithm()) {
    DLSequence der = (DLSequence) subjectPublicKeyInfo.parsePublicKey().toASN1Primitive();
    ASN1Object modulus, exponent;
    modulus = (ASN1Object) der.getObjectAt(0);
    exponent = (ASN1Object) der.getObjectAt(1);
    RSAPublicKeySpec spec =
            new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus.toString()), new BigInteger(exponent.toString()));
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    pubKey = factory.generatePublic(spec);
} else {
    // Throw some exception
}
```

I get a valid `PublicKey` and the algorithm is identified correctly.

Why does java's parser fails here? And am I doing the migration from `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` to `PublicKey` correctly?

**Update**:

I've tried to verify the key using `openssl`:

> $ openssl rsa -inform PEM -pubin -in pub.pem -text -noout
>   unable to load Public Key
>   140735659656136:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start
>   line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:704:Expecting:
>   PUBLIC KEY

And after removing `RSA` from the header / footer:

> $ openssl rsa -inform PEM -pubin -in pub.pem -text -noout unable to
>   load Public Key 140735659656136:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong
>   tag:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1164:
>   140735659656136:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1
>   error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:314:Type=X509_ALGOR
>   140735659656136:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1
>   error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:653:Field=algor,
>   Type=X509_PUBKEY 140735659656136:error:0906700D:PEM
>   routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1
>   lib:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/pem/pem_oth.c:84:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's parser didn't fail, your public key is *not* an instance of an encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure that Java's `X509EncodedKeySpec` is expecting. I haven't gone through the Bouncycastle routines to see why it succeeded, but PEMParser is designed to parse many different kinds of so-called "PEM" files.

A SubjectPublicKeyInfo is defined in [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) as:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
     subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING
}
```

Your public key is a simple PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey, defined in [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017) as:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
             modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
             publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
         }
```

And just a final word about "PEM" files. You need to be careful when describing something as "PEM" format because PEM is not really a specific format. "PEM" is little more than encoding a true format in base64, then wrapping the base64 in "-----BEGIN -----" and "-----END -----" lines, where *hopefully*  uniquely describes what the base64-encoded data is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what you are actually saying that BC "made up" the algorithm id or used a default one? Is there a good tool I can use to visualize/parse asn1 structures? Or should I do it manually?

Comment: My favorite tool is at https://lapo.it/asn1js/. It wants to see base64 encoded data, which it will then decode and parse, indent, show alg identifiers. Try it with your public key, but you have to get rid of the "BEGIN" and "END line, and all the quote and "\n" and so on so that you just have the base64 part.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: You are right, no algorithm id. The tool is really helpful! I can now dig into the weird structures Apple devices provide and make sense of why Java/openssl can't handle them...